# Return RedirectView

Tags: python, django

I need to return RedirectView. None of these work:

```
class FooView(View):
  return SomeRedirectView

class FooView(View):
  return SomeRedirectView.as_view()

class FooView(View):
  return HTTPResponseRedirect(SomeRedirectView)
```

How do I return RedirectView?

**Edit:** Guys, the idea is that I need to return from a Class. But Looks like one doesn't do it like that. Then how does one return from a Class?

**Edit2:** Sorry, I was not clear enought. I **know** how to use single RedirectView to redirect user. I have a RedirectView:

```
class MyRedirectView(RedirectView):
  def get_redirect_url():
    return 'www.google.com'
```

I need to have `MyRedirectView` as a separate view, because it is used as a standalone View somewhere. But then I have completely other View, and it has to use logic and then 'call' `MyRedirectView`.

The question is, how does `SomeOtherView` has to look like? (**not** `MyRedirectView`)

```
class SomeOtherView(View):
  def get():
    return MyRedirectView ????
```

**Solution:** With the help of other SO members I've came to conclusion that my thinking was wrong. I don't have to duplicate code, I can use function. I can't call class or return a view. But I can use public function and call it both from inside MyRedirectView and FooView (or any other views).

Thank you everyone for help and good discussion!

Comment: You need to start with reading a Python and a Django tutorial. In Python, you don't `return` from a class, and in Django you don't return a view.

Comment: Return from a Class - is exactly what I need :) The code used to be function-based, but has been migrated into class-based.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why you think you need to return a view at all. If your existing view needs to return a redirect, then you should simply do that:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect


class SomeOtherView(View):
  def get(request):
    ... logic here...
    return redirect(my_redirect_destination)
```

Comment: MyRedirectView has some code inside, related to gathering user statistics. So it is not just a simple redirect. The whole code used to be function-based, now it is class-based. That's why I have a problem - function-baseed pattern left. I used to call a function (that handles some business and returns redirect). Now I have a class (View). :(

Comment: So, why can't you put that code inside SomeOtherView - perhaps as a separate method you call from `get`?

Comment: I could do it, but then I will have to call the same code twice. So if I need to change it, I will have to go to 2 different places. Usually one uses a fucntion() for this purpose.

Comment: I guess my thinking is wrong. If people say 'In Python, you don't return from a class, and in Django you don't return a view', then I need to think about different solution..

Comment: So, call the function! Just because you have a class, doesn't mean you can't call a function from it. Or, you could put the logic into a method in a base class, and inherit from that in both of your views.

Comment: Yep, I went for this solution :)

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/class-based-views/base/#redirectview), **your view needs to be a subclass of the `RedirectView`:**

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView

class MyRedirectView(RedirectView):

    permanent = False
    query_string = True

    def get_redirect_url(self, pk):
        return reverse('example', args=(pk,))
```

*[Here's a good example](http://wisercoder.com/how-to-redirect-views-in-django/) using the base `RedirectView`*

---

Although you don't mention your `urls.py` file, you'll need to call `MyRedirectView.as_view()` in there. Again, great example in the docs. Here's the gist:

```
from views import MyRedirectView

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^someURL/$', MyRedirectView.as_view(), name='my-redirect-view'),
    ...
)
```

Comment: Thank you for this tip, but I need to return from RedirectView.

Comment: Why and what do you need to "return" from [the] RedirectView? The basic RedirectView uses a name/url that you pass it; **it does not return a view.** Check out this example: http://wisercoder.com/how-to-redirect-views-in-django/

Comment: I have 2 views. First view is a RedirectView and it redirects somewhere. Second view has to use first view to redirect somewhere.

Comment: Exactly. All you need to do is call the redirect view  as in the example. In fact, you actually don't even need a custom RedirectView class in that case; you can use the base one. : ) Make sense?

Comment: Yeah, but I don't want to call RedirectView inside urls.py :) I need to call RedirectView from inside View, because View has logic (IF statements, etc.). That's the problem. Edited the question to clarify :)

Comment: "I don't want to call RedirectView inside urls.py" -- **You need to do that regardless.** You can declare a custom Redirect, but in the end you still need to call the redirect from `urls.py`. **If you're using a RedirectView as a "standalone" view AND a redirect, you should just use two separate views.**